# Show C build results in Linux terminal with Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, sublimetext3, gnome-terminal

I'm using Sublime Text 3 for C programming. I want to compile and run my programs in the gnome terminal using a keybinding or something like that instead of the ST3 console (like CodeBlocks does). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click `Tools->Build System->New build system` to add a new build system, copy following code:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gnome-terminal -x bash -c \"gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} -lm -Wall; ./${file_base_name}; exec bash\""],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Save this file.

Then click `Tools->Build System` to choose the newly stored build system. Every time you press "Ctrl+B", the keybinding of `Tools->build`, it will run gnome-terminal and compile&run your program automatically.

Comment: Just curious: why is the `exec bash` needed at the end of the command ?